# Google Sheets Copy down formula with inserting a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am transitioning from Excel and VBA to Google Sheets and admittedly, don't know JavaScript.

I see that there is a common request for some VBA which will copy down the formulas from the row above, when I insert a new row anywhere in the dataset. I know how to add a butt, and i used the Macro Recorder to record the insertion of a Row, but the recorder only records that particular row that I chose to insert above.

I'd like the script to grab the activecell row number, so that it is dynamic on where ever my cursor is.

Here's the code I have so far. Can someone help me correct it?

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow().activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveCell().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getNumColumns()).activate();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can accomplish your goal by creating an [installable onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers).

Follow the instructions below to set it up. After the setup is completed, you **don't** execute `myFunction` manually. It will be executed automatically everytime you **insert a new row** in the active sheet.

```
function myFunction(e) {
 const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
 const row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
 const formulas = sh.getRange(row-1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getFormulasR1C1();
 sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setFormulasR1C1(formulas);  
  }
}
```

---

### Instructions:

1. Go to use the aforementioned code, **copy/paste** it to the script editor and click **save**.
2. Click on the current **project's triggers**:

[image: example]

3. Click on **add trigger** on the bottom right side of the page.
4. And then use **exactly** these settings:

[image: settings]

Comment: Thank you Marios!   It worked well, except that when it copied the formula down, it did not change the row reference to the new inserted row.    What do i need to change to make that happen?     Also, do you have any recommendations as to where i can self-learn javascript for Google sheets?

Comment: @Hilly1 please try my updated answer. You can check the official documentation but also tutorials online.

Comment: Also, when I select a row, does this work off of the Left Click option of (a) "Insert 1 Row Above, or (b) "Insert 1 Row Below, or both?

Comment: @Hilly1 only below but I can make it work in both ways. Please accept the answer if it helped you and consider voting up

Comment: What change did you make?   I don't see any change to the event Trigger parameters.

Comment: Absolutely, I will vote up!  You are very helpful and responsive.  I didn't know how this site worked.   Can you send me code to work either way, as I can't control which option the user will select.    I cut/pasted your code again, but didn't notice any change.  Was i supposed to edit the trigger parameters too?

Comment: @Hilly1 okay, please try again my solution. The code works both ways (either adding below or above). The only requirement in both cases, is that the row exactly above the newly created should contain a formula. Let me know if it worked.