# Using If Contains Type Function To Send Email to Specific Address Based on Substring within Current Row and Column

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send an email message to a specific email address any time a new row is added that contains "Robotics/Automation" in that current row and a specific column. The cell that contains that string may also contain other strings, so I want to figure out a way to use an "if contains" type function to send the email if "Robotics/Automation" appears anywhere in that specific column and current row. Currently, the code I have now is as follows:

```
function emailRobotics(e) { 
  if(regexmatch(e.range.getRow() & e.range.getColumn() == 13, "Robotics/Automation")) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var subject = "Robotics/Automation Request";
    var message = "Hello, a Robotics/Automation request was sent into the request form";
    MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com", subject, message);
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be great! I've tried using regexmatch and it does not seem to be working for me, but I also may not be using it correctly.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to use and installable onEdit() which is a good choice however it only responds to user edits it won’t respond to any script edits or formula edits. There is no trigger to my knowledge that performs in the way that you desire. You could try a time based trigger and Poll for changes

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037593/google-sheets-copy-down-formula-with-inserting-a-row) might be related to your issue. You can use this logic to execute code when a new row is added.

Comment: If the question is about "If Contains Type Function", we should clarify: use [JS match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function directly. The 2-nd code line needs some comments, I don't understand it. Does your code run without errors?