# google Script copying down formulas to new inserted row clears row data when row is moved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a google script to copy formulas to new inserted rows with an onChange trigger (reference: [Google Sheets Copy down formula with inserting a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037593/google-sheets-copy-down-formula-with-inserting-a-row?rq=3)) and it works perfectly when adding a new row but the problem is when I move a row in the sheet it seems to treat the row moved as a new row and clears the values inside the row moved and places the formulas.
How to get the script to ignore rows that are simply moved? I Would greatly appreciate any help. Below is the script I'm using:

```
function addRowWithFormulas(e) {
 const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
 const row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
 const formulas = sh.getRange(row-1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getFormulasR1C1();
 sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setFormulas(formulas);  
  }
}
```

I searched for any comments regarding this issue but did not find anything to adapt this script to my needs.

Comment: there is a way to write your formula in just ONE row, but have it apply to all the rows without having to have it copied to each row.  then a script would be entirely unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

When onChange triggers it uses an event object with the info of the change, [there is an example here for onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) using that object to get the range that was modified. Something similar can be done but with onChange which [as shown here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#events) has a changeType property where the value will be INSERT_ROW when a row is inserted, so you can make a simple if, for when the value of the object is INSERT_ROW then, execute your code to copy your formulas and do nothing when the other changes happen.