# Is there a way to automatically apply a function from another cell when adding a row from Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

When I add a new row as shown in the figure below, I want to apply the same function to other areas (column N in the figure). Is there any way?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Copy down formula with inserting a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037593/google-sheets-copy-down-formula-with-inserting-a-row)

Comment: P.S. It would be better to change the interface language to English, before creating/posting such an animated GIF.